# can't get this python program to work

Tags: python, pygame

This is the `vector2` module:

```
class Vector2(object):
    "this calculates the vector between two points"
    def __init__(self , x = 0.0, y = 0.0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return "( %s,%s )"%(self.x, self.y)

    @classmethod
    def from_points(cls,p1,p2):
        return cls(p2[0]-p1[0],p2[1]-p1[1])

     #the magnetude of a vector is the distance between two points
    def get_magnetude(self):
        return math.sqrt(self.x**2+self.y**2)

    def normalize(self):
        magnetude = self.get_magnetude()
        self.x /= magnetude
        self.y /= magnetude

    #rhs stands for right hand side
    def __add__(self,rhs):
        return Vector2(self.x + rhs.x,self.y+rhs.y)

    def __sub__(self,rhs):
        return Vector2(self.x-rhs.x,self.y-rhs.y)

    def __neg__(self):
        return Vector2(-self.x, -self.y)

    def __mul__(self,scalar):
        return Vector2(self.x*scalar,self.y*scalar)

    def  __div__(self,scalar):
        return Vector2(self.x /scalar, self.y/scalar)
```

And this is the main program, which imports `vector2`:

```
background_image_file = 'download.jpeg'
sprite_image_file = 'images.jpeg'

import math 
import pygame 
from pygame.locals import*
from sys import exit
import vector2


pygame.init()

screen  = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480), 0 ,32)

background = pygame.image.load(background_image_file).convert()
sprite = pygame.image.load(sprite_image_file).convert_alpha()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()


position = Vector2(100.0, 100.0)#the starting point coordonates
heading = Vector2()#a vector without its magnetude(unit vector)
speed = 250.0

running = True 

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            exit()

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            destination_x = event.pos[0]-sprite.get_width()/2
            destination_y =event.pos[1]-sprite.get_height()/2
            destination = (destination_x, destination_y)
            heading = Vector2.get_magnetude(position,destination)#
            heading.normalize()#a vector without magnetude,just direction

    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    screen.blit(sprite, position)

    time_passed = clock.tick()
    time_passed_seconds = time_passed / 1000.0
    distance_moved = time_passed_seconds * speed
    position += (heading * distance_moved)

    pygame.display.update()
```

I am learning Python and pygame by my self with (Beginning Game Development with Python and Pygame - From Novice to Professional (2007)) and I can't get the program to work. Also can someone please explain to me why the author use `position = Vector2(100.0,100.0)` and `position = Vector2()` to create new vectors?

It keeps saying :

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/moussa/Documents/python /vector_movement.py", line 21, in <module>
    position = Vector2(100.0, 100.0)#the starting point coordonates
NameError: name 'Vector2' is not defined
```

Comment: @adchilds That is incorrect. Assuming that the class `Vector2` is in the file `vector2`, what is needed is to either refer to it by `vector2.Vector2` or use `from vector2 import Vector2`.

Comment: Is the code shown in the question all in one file, or is is split in two where the "#the main program starts from here" comment is? The exception you're getting doesn't make any sense if it's all in one file, but does if the top part is in `vector2.py`.

Comment: its actually two separate codes but within the same folder.so i just imported the Vector2 in order to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that the code in the question is actually split between two files, one with the `Vector2` class (in `vector2.py`) and the rest in some other file (which imports `vector2`).

The issue you're running into is that you're not accessing the class correctly. In your main module, you need to use `vector2.Vector2` to access the class within its module.

Or, if you'd prefer to have easier access to the class, you could instead change your import from `import vector2` to `from vector2 import Vector2`. This puts the class into the main module's namespace, so you can access it directly as `Vector2`.

As for the use of `position = Vector2(100.0,100.0)`, this is a call to the `Vector2` class's constructor. It creates an instance of the class, initializes it with the values `100` for `x` and `100` for `y`, and then binds it to the variable `position`. You can then use the various methods and operators that the class defines to update the instance, or get new values. For instance, the later line `position += (heading * distance_moved)` first multiplies the vector `heading` by the scalar `distance_moved`, then adds the vector result to `position`. You could do this with values in lists or tuples, but it would be much more complicated (you'd need to add and multiply the components of the vectors yourself).

Comment: I meant i dont get the meaning of using Vector2 to create a new vector since its a class,so it doesnt make sens to me a create the new vector from a class.wouldnt it be the same if say position = [100.0,100.0]?i hope its clearer now.thanks

Comment: @user2983686: I've updated my answer to try to explain a bit of what is going on there. If you still don't understand it, you may want to check out a tutorial on Python object oriented programming, such as [this page of the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).